# Creating/Saving a Vim Layout

Tags: session, vim, panes, neovim

Everytime I open a project/directory I use the exact same vim pane layout:

```
 ---------
|    |pane|
|pane|pane|
|    |pane|
 ---------
```

I would like to be able to open a new vim session with this layout, all of the panes on the right would start in `:Explore` mode, while the left pane would start in `:terminal` mode (specific to neovim).

Is there any way to create a vim "layout" for a new session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
nvim -c ':vsp|Explore|sp|Explore|sp|Explore'
```

Placing terminal in front is tricky because it steals focus.

Now I got a idea.

```
nvim -c ':vsp|Explore|sp|Explore|sp|Explore|wincmd w|te'
```

Comment: This is so close :D - tho the terminal doesn't open up, unless I'm not waiting long enough

Comment: it's also backwards compared to my example, which is fine

Comment: You can open terminal last, but if you open it first it steals focus and stops the command chain.

Comment: after your edit, I attempted again: here's the [outcome](https://cldup.com/Le6HbZL5aI.png).

Could you explain the `wincmd w|te`?

Comment: Lol strange, it look opposite on my machine. Do you use neovim and if so what version? Wincmd w means <C-W>w(next window command). , te is shortcut for terminal command.

Comment: I'm running neovim v0.1.0, build type: Release (locally built)

Comment: Mine is v0.1.1....... Try running this command inside Neovim one by one and see what happens. Later try to compose them to get the wanted output.
 Try using terminal instead of te......

Comment: so the sequence that makes it work (cept is opposite of the layout that I have above)

`nvim -c ':vsp|Explore|sp|Explore|sp|Explore|wincmd w|wincmd w|wincmd w|te'`

Comment: do you know a way to shorten that? ^

Comment: The layout is exactly as you draw it on my machine.... funny... maybe is the neovim version..

Comment: Try: Ve for vertical split and explore and Hex for horizontal split and explore.     But you should map it in your terminal to something more appropriate...

Comment: Updated to nevim v0.1.1
Here's my cmd to make it work as I illustrated above:

`nvim -c ':vsp|wincmd w|Explore|sp|sp|wincmd h|terminal'` - tho i'm not in insert/append mode, but I am focused in the terminal